# Why is 'not' not working when used with a dictionary?

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, if-statement, logical-operators

```
class Enemy(object):
    def __init__(self, name, hp, damage):
       self.name = name
       self.hp = hp
       self.damage = damage

    def is_alive(self):
       return self.hp > 0

enemies = {}

enemies['dog'] = Enemy("Dog", 20, 5)

if enemies['dog'].is_alive:
   print("Woof, Woof!")

enemies['dog'].hp = 0

print(enemies['dog'].hp)

if not enemies['dog'].is_alive:
   print("The dog is dead")
```

As shown above, I have created a class that has a function which checks the amount of one of the variables. When I run it, it works, however, when is use 'not' to get it to print when it is 0, it does not print anything, even though I changed the variable to 0. I checked it by printing the HP out, after changing it and it did change.

Is it possible whether anyone can tell me why it is not printing? I have tried searching for an answer but am unable to find anything. Please help!

Comment: You should be calling `is_alive()` with parentheses. Otherwise you are just referencing the method without calling.

Comment: You can decorate `is_alive` with `@property` so that you can call it without parentheses: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property

Answer (score 4):

`is_alive` is a function which is not `None`, empty string, `0`, `[]`, `(,)` etc. so it evaluates to `True` when used within an if statement.

```
>>> func = lambda: False
>>> if func:
...     print("ehehe")
ehehe

>>> if func():
...     print("ehehe")
```

You should call the function to get the return value:

```
>>> if enemies['dog'].is_alive():
...     print("Woof, Woof!")
```

BTW, you can use [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) decorator to get rid of parentheses when calling the method:

```
@property
def is_alive(self):
   return self.hp > 0
```

Comment: So without calling the function, is_alive will always evaluate to true, regardless of whether I put 'not' before it? Is that correct? If so, why? PS: Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it always evaluates to `True`. If you put `not` before it, it will always evaluate to `False` like `if (not True):` always being evaluated to false.

Answer (score 1):

`is_alive` is a method, so it needs parentheses. There is no difference in the assignment to a dictionary vs just an ordinary variable.

```
class Enemy(object):
    def __init__(self, name, hp, damage):
       self.name = name
       self.hp = hp
       self.damage = damage

    def is_alive(self):
       return self.hp > 0

enemies = {}

enemies['dog'] = Enemy("Dog", 20, 5)
print enemies['dog'].is_alive() 
enemies['dog'].hp = 0
print enemies['dog'].hp 
print enemies['dog'].is_alive()

print

a = Enemy("Dog", 20, 5)
print a.is_alive()
a.hp = 0
print(a.hp)
print a.is_alive()

if not a.is_alive():
    print 'dog is dead'
```

Output:

```
True
0
False

True
0
False
dog is dead
```